# Flutter cached image is it possible to reload image instead of getting the cached image?

Tags: image, firebase, flutter, caching

I'm using the package flutter_cached_network_image to load images from firebase. When a user updates his profile picture (filename is still the same) the image that is loaded is still the same as the one before the update because it is loaded from cache (because it still has the same url as before).
Is it possible to clear the picture from the cache so the new image is loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there is no solution at the moment. See here: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/77

I use the version of the image in the address to get around this. Something like: https://example.com/image.jpg?version=14

Comment: Thank you. Where does the version number come from? Is it an additional variable you keep track of?

Comment: In my case, every time the user changes the photo, I increment the version in a database. But as @Renê commented, this can be achieved in several ways (Ex: Random class)

Comment: Use a random number instead of keeping a track

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. This helped me this:

```
imageCache.clearLiveImages();
imageCache.clear();
_bloc.add(ReloadEvent());
```

Cleaning cache and rebuilding widgets after successfully updating photo.

Comment: Running the two lines (clearLiveImages and then clear) fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Like @EderBaum said, you can force puting an additional query string input, the value depends of the effect that you want, for example:

1 - Never cache
http:urlofresource.com/yourimage.jpg?version={NewRandonNumberGenerated}

You can use `Random` class to achieve this.

2- Reload cache based on app version

Same that before, but now, you use an version information that you can put into your global state or somewhere else to retrieve information after an update

3 - Use normal cache

Just leave the widget do the job.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. I'm now tracking the version number for each users profile picture so when the version number changes the url changes because of the version={newVersionNumber} in the end

Comment: You're welcome! If I helps you, can you please up vote my awnser? Thanks!